# Referencing something that isn't a lemma, proposition etc...

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

I need to reference a fact that is in another paper. It is stated after a lemma, and follows from this, thought perhaps not very directly.

I could just reference it as "see [1, Pg. 5]" or "see [1, Page 5]" (I am assuming my bibliography is just labelled "1, 2, 3..." for ease)

Alternatively, I could say "As stated after Lemma 2.6 in [1]". However, I am not sure if the use "Lemma 2.6" in this case should only be used to refer to lemmas in the paper that it is written in.

Finally, I could say "see comments immediately after [1, Lem. 2.6]", but then I imagine if someone skims it they might look at the lemma itself, which is not the relevant point.

I feel like the middle case is best, but I didn't know if there was unwritten rule saying not to do this.

Comment: Middle case sounds good to me.

Comment: I feel that the second and third are more or less equivalent, and which you use is then a question of the actual fact that is being referred to and how it is presented in ref. [1].  The point is to see in any particular case which form works best for you (and test it on others).  Don't worry about unwritten rules, seek clarity of express instead. (Unwritten rules may be right or wrong, and as they are unwritten how can one tell. ;-))

Comment: The titles like "Lemma", "Theorem" etc. are not only for easier reading, but, among others, for referencing. If you would like reference something other, put it into a relevant block, like "Fact 2.7" and then reference it as you would any other label. I've also seen $$\text{this kind of thing (for text),}\tag{$2.7$}$$ but I guess it's not what you would like to do. 

If you want to keep it as a regular text, you could reference it using symbols like$^\dagger$ this$^1$ (a footnote might also help). Finally, from your suggestions I would pick "see comments immediately after [1, Lem. 2.6]".

Comment: @dtldarek I think you might have misunderstood my point. I can't choose how to format what I wish to reference, since it is not in my paper. My point was whether using Lemma, Theorem etc is exclusively reserved lemmas, theorems, etc in the current one is writing

Comment: @JoeTait Ahh, right, sorry. In this regard, any block (e.g. Lemma) relies on its context, papers are not reducible to block-part-only. Hence, referencing this context (here the comments following a lemma) would be alright (and doing so by referencing a nearby lemma is OK too). On the other hand, be aware that papers might be revised and then the text and comments may change (this also affects theorems and lemmas but not as much as other things), so you should cite journal or conference edition (i.e. fixed) or include version (date?) when citing arXiv or other sources that could change later.

Comment: @dtldarek Thank you for the point about arxiv ec - fortunately the paper I am referencing was published a couple of years ago, so in this instance that should be fine. Thanks for the comments :)